# How to create a discrete normal distribution in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create a discrete normal distribution using something such as

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 350, sd = 20)
```

but I don't think the `rnorm` function has a built in "discrete numbers only" option. I have spent a few hours trying to search this on StackOverflow, Google and R documentation but have yet to find anything.

Comment: What is a "discrete normal distribution"? I'm not familiar with this type of distribution.

Comment: If you mean the best discrete approximation to a continuous distribution, I think you'll have to code it up yourself. Here's a simple note on the topic: http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~jkennan/research/DiscreteApprox.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, there is no discrete normal distribution as by default it is continuous. However, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) (Wikipedia is not the best possible source but this is correct anyway):

> If n is large enough, then the skew of the distribution is not too great. In this case a reasonable approximation to B(n, p) is given by the normal distribution

This can be seen with a quick example:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2) )
#values generated by a binomial distribution
plot(density(rbinom(1000, 30, p=0.25)))
#values generated by a normal distribution
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
```

Plot:

[image]

The graph on the left (binomial) certainly approximates the right (normal) and this will get more obvious as `n goes to Inf`.

As you will see `rbinom(1000, 30, p=0.25)` will produce discrete values (integers). Also, density is probably not the best function to use on a discrete variable, but it proves the point here.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to generate a set of random integers following a normal distribution you could simply round them like so...

```
    round(rnorm(10, 5, 1), 0)
```

Comment: A "set of random integers following a normal distribution" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(extraDistr)
set.seed(12)
rdnorm(10)
```